# Pycharm не распознает файл main.css (ссылка на неразрешенный шаблон) (Django)

Tags: python, django, pycharm, static

Я использую Django с Pycharm.

Я начал использовать Pycharm Professional сегодня, и Pycharm не распознает мой файл main.css,
ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Unresolved template reference ''advert/css/main.css''

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'advert/css/main.css' %}">
```

`{% load static %}` присутствует, ссылка идет после бутстрапа, сам бустрап работает.

`django.contrib.staticfiles` в `INSTALLED_APPS` в `файле settings.py` имеется.

Иерархия каталогов проекта

[image: Иерархия каталогов проекта]

static_dir, staticfiles_dirs, base_dir и static_root.

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATIC_ROOT = "VSS/advert/static"
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_ROOT)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

Так же используется шаблон Django

[image: Django template]

Почему PyCharm не "понимает" путь к css файлу, хотя подключил bootstrap стили?

Может проблема в моих настройках проекта или пайчарма?

Если я не ставил виртуальную среду для Django это может сказаться на данной проблеме?

upd:
На IDE Atom, та же проблема, на сайте не меняется *background*, который прописан в `main.css`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127839/discussion-on-question-by-mmbest1-pycharm----main-css--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зайдите в Настройки в Pycharm

**Settings >> Project Setting >> Django**

Включите поддержку Django и укажите пути для трех следующих файлов:

```
Project Root
Settings file
Manage.py file
```

Когда вы предоставите эту информацию, закройте PyCharm и перезапустите его.

Ответ был найден [здесь..](https://code-examples.net/en/q/8181f2)